# Fix perl text>xml convertor script

Tags: xml, linux, perl, text, ipmi

Trying to use IPMI templates making scripts from here: http://www.tune-it.ru/web/tiamat/home/-/blogs/17465 using the first perl script. So I got the next output:

```
# template|sensor|type|dsc|unit|lnr|lcr|lnc|unc|ucr|unr
|1.05V PCH|Threshold|Voltage|Volts|0.870|0.897|0.942|1.194|1.221|1.248
|1.2V BMC|Threshold|Voltage|Volts|1.020|1.047|1.092|1.344|1.371|1.398
|1.5V PCH|Threshold|Voltage|Volts|1.320|1.347|1.401|1.644|1.671|1.698
|12V|Threshold|Voltage|Volts|10.173|10.299|10.740|12.945|13.260|13.386
|3.3VCC|Threshold|Voltage|Volts|2.789|2.823|2.959|3.554|3.656|3.690
|3.3VSB|Threshold|Voltage|Volts|2.789|2.823|2.959|3.554|3.656|3.690
|5VCC|Threshold|Voltage|Volts|4.246|4.298|4.480|5.390|5.546|5.598
|5VSB|Threshold|Voltage|Volts|4.246|4.298|4.480|5.390|5.546|5.598
|CPU Temp|Threshold|Temperature|degrees C|0.000|0.000|0.000|85.000|90.000|90.000
|Chassis Intru|Discrete|Physical Security|discrete||||||
|DIMMA1 Temp|Threshold|Temperature|degrees C|1.000|2.000|4.000|80.000|85.000|90.000
|DIMMA2 Temp|Threshold|Temperature|degrees C|1.000|2.000|4.000|80.000|85.000|90.000
|DIMMB1 Temp|Threshold|Temperature|degrees C|1.000|2.000|4.000|80.000|85.000|90.000
|DIMMB2 Temp|Threshold|Temperature|degrees C|1.000|2.000|4.000|80.000|85.000|90.000
|DIMMC1 Temp|Threshold|Temperature|||||||
|DIMMC2 Temp|Threshold|Temperature|||||||
|DIMMD1 Temp|Threshold|Temperature|||||||
|DIMMD2 Temp|Threshold|Temperature|||||||
|FAN1|Threshold|Fan|RPM|300.000|500.000|700.000|25300.000|25400.000|25500.000
|FAN2|Threshold|Fan|RPM|300.000|500.000|700.000|25300.000|25400.000|25500.000
|FAN3|Threshold|Fan|RPM|300.000|500.000|700.000|25300.000|25400.000|25500.000
|FAN4|Threshold|Fan|RPM|300.000|500.000|700.000|25300.000|25400.000|25500.000
|FAN5|Threshold|Fan|||||||
|FANA|Threshold|Fan|||||||
|PCH Temp|Threshold|Temperature|degrees C|-11.000|-8.000|-5.000|90.000|95.000|100.000
|PS1 Status|Discrete|Power Supply|discrete||||||
|PS2 Status|Discrete|Power Supply|discrete||||||
|Peripheral Temp|Threshold|Temperature|degrees C|-9.000|-7.000|-5.000|80.000|85.000|90.000
|System Temp|Threshold|Temperature|degrees C|-9.000|-7.000|-5.000|80.000|85.000|90.000
|VBAT|Threshold|Voltage|Volts|2.375|2.487|2.599|3.775|3.887|3.999
|VDIMMAB|Threshold|Voltage|Volts|0.948|0.975|1.047|1.344|1.425|1.443
|VDIMMCD|Threshold|Voltage|Volts|0.948|0.975|1.047|1.344|1.425|1.443
|Vcpu|Threshold|Voltage|Volts|1.242|1.260|1.395|1.899|2.088|2.106
|VcpuVRM Temp|Threshold|Temperature|degrees C|-9.000|-7.000|-5.000|95.000|100.000|105.000
|VmemABVRM Temp|Threshold|Temperature|degrees C|-9.000|-7.000|-5.000|95.000|100.000|105.000
|VmemCDVRM Temp|Threshold|Temperature|degrees C|-9.000|-7.000|-5.000|95.000|100.000|105.000
```

When I ran the 2nd script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $date = strftime("%d.%m.%y", localtime);
my $time = strftime("%H.%M", localtime);

my $delay = 300;
my $history = 7;
my $trends = 365;

# 0 - Line
# 1 - Fill
# 2 - Bold line
# 3 - Dots
# 4 - Striped line
# 5 - Gradient line

my $drawtype = 1;

# 3 - Number (Integer)
# 0 - Number (Folating point)
# 1 - Symbol
# 2 - Log
# 4 - Text

my %sensor_type = (
        Discrete => 3,
        Analog => 0,
);

# 0 - Unclassified
# 1 - Notification
# 2 - Warning
# 3 - Middle
# 4 - High
# 5 - Extreme

my @thresh_type = (
        { pri => 4, dsc => 'Lower Non-Recoverable' },
        { pri => 3, dsc => 'Lower Critical' },
        { pri => 2, dsc => 'Lower Non-Critical' },
        { pri => 2, dsc => 'Upper Non-Critical' },
        { pri => 3, dsc => 'Upper Critical' },
        { pri => 4, dsc => 'Upper Non-Recoverable' },
);

my $head = <<EOF;
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<zabbix_export version="1.0" date="%s" time="%s">
        <hosts>
                <host name="%s">
                        <proxy_hostid>0</proxy_hostid>
                        <useip>0</useip>
                        <dns></dns>
                        <ip>0.0.0.0</ip>
                        <port>10050</port>
                        <status>3</status>
                        <useipmi>0</useipmi>
                        <ipmi_ip></ipmi_ip>
                        <ipmi_port>623</ipmi_port>
                        <ipmi_authtype>0</ipmi_authtype>
                        <ipmi_privilege>2</ipmi_privilege>
                        <ipmi_username></ipmi_username>
                        <ipmi_password></ipmi_password>
                        <groups>
                                <group>Templates</group>
                        </groups>
                        <items>
%s
                        </items>
                        <triggers>
%s
                        </triggers>
                        <graphs>
%s
                        </graphs>
                        <templates/>
                        <macros/>
                </host>
        </hosts>
        <dependencies/>
</zabbix_export>
EOF

my $item = <<EOF;
                                <item type="12" key="%s" value_type="%d">
                                        <description>%s</description>
                                        <ipmi_sensor>%s</ipmi_sensor>
                                        <delay>$delay</delay>
                                        <history>$history</history>
                                        <trends>$trends</trends>
                                        <status>0</status>
                                        <data_type>0</data_type>
                                        <units>%s</units>
                                        <multiplier>0</multiplier>
                                        <delta>0</delta>
                                        <formula>1</formula>
                                        <lastlogsize>0</lastlogsize>
                                        <logtimefmt></logtimefmt>
                                        <delay_flex></delay_flex>
                                        <authtype>0</authtype>
                                        <username></username>
                                        <password></password>
                                        <publickey></publickey>
                                        <privatekey></privatekey>
                                        <params></params>
                                        <trapper_hosts></trapper_hosts>
                                        <snmp_community></snmp_community>
                                        <snmp_oid></snmp_oid>
                                        <snmp_port>161</snmp_port>
                                        <snmpv3_securityname></snmpv3_securityname>
                                        <snmpv3_securitylevel>0</snmpv3_securitylevel>
                                        <snmpv3_authpassphrase></snmpv3_authpassphrase>
                                        <snmpv3_privpassphrase></snmpv3_privpassphrase>
                                        <applications/>
                                </item>
EOF

my $trigger = <<EOF;
                                <trigger>
                                        <description>%s</description>
                                        <type>0</type>
                                        <expression>%s</expression>
                                        <url></url>
                                        <status>0</status>
                                        <priority>%d</priority>
                                        <comments>%s</comments>
                                </trigger>
EOF

my $graph = <<EOF;
                                <graph name="%s" width="900" height="200">
                                        <ymin_type>0</ymin_type>
                                        <ymax_type>0</ymax_type>
                                        <ymin_item_key></ymin_item_key>
                                        <ymax_item_key></ymax_item_key>
                                        <show_work_period>1</show_work_period>
                                        <show_triggers>1</show_triggers>
                                        <graphtype>0</graphtype>
                                        <yaxismin>0.0000</yaxismin>
                                        <yaxismax>100.0000</yaxismax>
                                        <show_legend>0</show_legend>
                                        <show_3d>0</show_3d>
                                        <percent_left>0.0000</percent_left>
                                        <percent_right>0.0000</percent_right>
                                        <graph_elements>
                                                <graph_element item="%s">
                                                        <drawtype>$drawtype</drawtype>
                                                        <sortorder>0</sortorder>
                                                        <color>009900</color>
                                                        <yaxisside>0</yaxisside>
                                                        <calc_fnc>2</calc_fnc>
                                                        <type>0</type>
                                                        <periods_cnt>$delay</periods_cnt>
                                                </graph_element>
                                        </graph_elements>
                                </graph>
EOF

my ($tname, $items, $triggers, $graphs);
while (<>) {
        chomp;
        next if /^#/;
        my ($template,$sensor,$type,$dsc,$unit,$lnr,$lcr,$lnc,$unc,$ucr,$unr) =
                split(/\|/);

        $template = "Template_$template";
        $tname = $template;

        my $key = sprintf("%s_%s_%s", $type, $dsc, $unit);
        $key =~ s/[\s\\\/]+/_/g;
        $key = sprintf("%s[%s]", $key, $sensor);

        $items .= sprintf($item, $key, $sensor_type{$type},
                        "$type sensor for $dsc $sensor ($unit)", $sensor, $unit);

        if ($type eq 'Discrete') {
                $triggers .= sprintf($trigger, 
                        "$type sensor for $dsc $sensor on {HOSTNAME} was changed",
                        sprintf("{%s:%s.diff(0)}#0", $template, $key), 4, '');
        } elsif ($type eq 'Analog') {
                my $index = -1;
                my $op = '#';
                foreach my $tv ($lnr,$lcr,$lnc,$unc,$ucr,$unr) {
                        $index++;
                        next if ($tv =~ /^$/);
                        my $td = $thresh_type[$index]->{dsc};
                        my $tp = $thresh_type[$index]->{pri};
                        $op = '&lt;' if ($index < 3);
                        $op = '&gt;' if ($index > 2);
                        $triggers .= sprintf($trigger,
                                "$type sensor for $dsc $sensor on {HOSTNAME} changed to $td",
                                sprintf("{%s:%s.last(0)}%s%s", $template, $key, $op, $tv), $tp, '');
                }
                $graphs .= sprintf($graph, "$type sensor for $dsc $sensor ($unit)",
                                "$template:$key");
        } else {
                die "unknown sensor type: $type\n";
        }
}

printf($head, $date, $time, $tname, $items, $triggers, $graphs);
```

using this command

```
# perl /usr/local/etc/zabbix3/zabbix/externalscripts/get_ipmi.pl -H 192.168.1.100 -U ADMIN -P ADMIN | perl /usr/local/etc/zabbix3/zabbix/externalscripts/make_ipmi.pl > Supermicro_SYS-5018R_MR.xml
```

I got the message:

```
unknown sensor type: Threshold
```

I think, the 2nd column is already "Threshold" type, not digits. That's the reason of error.

How to change this part of source:

```
my %sensor_type = (
        Discrete => 3,
        Analog => 0,
);
```

for my text output example?
I am not a perl programmer. So any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not that simple.
You also have code looking only at Discrete and Analog in

```
if ($type eq 'Discrete') {
    ...
} elsif ($type eq 'Analog') {
    ...
}  else {
            die "unknown sensor type: $type\n";
}
```

You would need to either add a section to specifically deal with "Threshold" or, allow it to use the code from either the "Discrete" section or the "Analog" section.

Since you have fractional numbers in the fields of the Threshold lines, you could try these 2 edits:

```
my %sensor_type = (
    Discrete => 3,
    Analog => 0,
    Threshold => 0,  # <-- this is the added line
);
```

and change the  line `elsif ($type eq 'Analog')` to

```
} elsif ($type eq 'Analog' or $type eq 'Threshold') {
```

But, having only looked at the code briefly, it might still have other problems trying to work with Threshold that I overlooked.